# How to make visible to users the copyright of Google fonts (if we must to do it)?

Tags: google-fonts

Downloaded Google fonts family archive including the `TTF` file and `LICENSE.txt`.
Now: how I should to make this license visible to website or web/native application users (if I should)?

- `LICENSE.txt` includes about 200 lines of text. Of course, nobody links to it in their footers.
- If just include `LICENSE.txt` in the web application files, nobody can check it unless they directly go to something like https://example.new/files/PATH/TO/LICENSE.txt.
- For native applications case, users basically can not check the contents of the built application.

Comment: You could take this question over to https://opensource.stackexchange.com, there are similar questions there. For natives apps it is not unheard of having a license info view somewhere in the help or about section of the app.